# Input method program with python

Tags: python, windows

I am making a mouse-enabled Chinese input method for my Dad (he doesn't know how to type) using Python. I couldn't quite find out how to use Python to send Chinese characters to the window of another program.

The closest I found was `SendKeys` , but it seems to only be able to send keystrokes, not characters. I realized Python might not be the best tool for this purpose. However, being a programming hobbist, I'm most comfortable with Python. I wonder if there is a way out there that I missed...

Comment: is the goal to "learn" how to build virtual keyboards? or just to help Dad out? If latter, there's probably some options available online. Just search for virtual keyboards in chinese or something

Comment: On pretty much all computers, there's an "accessibility keyboard" which you use the mouse for. Just change your input language to Chinese, bring it up, and you (or your dad) are set to go.

Comment: Maybe it depends on what OS dad is using. so you should add windows or macos or linux tag to this question.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh It's to help dad out. The problem is, Dad doesn't know how to use any of the input methods (pinyin, wubi). He is used to typing on the old Nokia phone, which uses the order of the strokes of each character (I use this amazing library https://github.com/YQ-YSY/stroke-seq_MB). I can only find one program online that does this, but its a bloatware with lots of popup adds and viruses. So, I am doing this as a side project.

Comment: @JackBashford The problem is, my dad can't use any of the traditional input methods. That's why I am making a new one for him. It's based on the order in which each stroke of the character is written, as opposed to pinyin or wubi.

Comment: I know nothing about Chinese IMEs, but some actual terminology might help here. Are you talking about reimplementing [O9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q9_input_method)?

Comment: @tripleee Wow, Q9 actually looks promising, I'll look into it. And yes, probably something like Q9.